# MediaStreamRecorder and TypeScript Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, audio, typescript, media

I am currently developing an audio recorder that uses the users PC microphone, which works fine. However, when I want to record the audio I get this type error:

> audioHandler.ts:45 Uncaught TypeError: MediaStreamRecorder is not a function

This is the code:

```
/// <reference path="../references.d.ts" />
//This component handles all things audio related

export = Scaut.AudioHandler;

module Scaut.AudioHandler {

    var n = <any>navigator;
    var stream = <any>"";
    var stopRecording = <any>"";
    var mediaRecorder = <any>"";
    //var MediaStreamRecorder = <any>""; 

    //Check if microphone is ok
    export function hasGetUserMedia() {
        n.getUserMedia = n.getUserMedia ||
        n.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        n.mozGetUserMedia;

        if (n.getUserMedia) {
            n.getUserMedia({ audio: true},
                function (stream) {
                    var audio = <any>"";
                    audio = document.getElementById('audioRecord');
                    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    audio.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                        audio.play();
                    };
                },
                function (err) {
                    alert("The following error occured: " + err.name);
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert("getUserMedia not supported");
        }

        recordAudio(stream);
    }

    //Record audio
    export function recordAudio(stream) {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
        console.log("Stream: "+stream)
        mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/ogg';
        mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
            // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2
            var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //document.write('<a href="' + blobURL + '">' + blobURL + '</a>');
            console.log("Blob: "+blob)
            console.log("BlobUrl: "+blobURL)
        };
        mediaRecorder.start(3000);
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you import the https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder  on your file ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your error is at compile time (as the error message points to your `.ts` file).

The error means that the compile is unaware of the `MediaStreamRecorder` type, which I am assuming you are importing from a JavaScript library.

To clear the error, you can make a simple type definition for it using the following like of code...

```
declare var MediaStreamRecorder: any;
```

This will clear the error, but won't give you any further type checking or auto-completion for the type. [You can add more detail to your type definition](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/) to improve this situation if you need to.

Comment: Thanks Fenton! That was exactly what I was looking for. Actually, I have just bought your book Pro TypeScript and received it today, looking forward to dive into it.

Comment: You're welcome - and thank you for buying my book :)